# FIDO2 compatibility with U2F/CTAP1

Tags: webauthn, fido-u2f, fido

There are many sources that say FIDO2/CTAP2 is backward compatible with U2F:

> ...all previously certified FIDO U2F Security Keys and YubiKeys will continue to work as a second-factor authentication login experience with web browsers and online services supporting WebAuthn. - *[Yubico](https://www.yubico.com/blog/10-things-youve-been-wondering-about-fido2-webauthn-and-a-passwordless-world/)*

But after looking at the specifications, I'm having trouble seeing how that actually works in practice. Specifically, it seems like there is a mismatch between FIDO2's [relying party identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#relying-party-identifier) and U2F's [application identity](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-v1.2-ps-20170411/fido-u2f-raw-message-formats-v1.2-ps-20170411.html#registration-request-message---u2f_register).

In U2F, the *application identity* is a URL, like `https://example.com`. SHA-256 of the application identity is called the *application parameter*. The *application parameter* is what is actually sent to the authenticator during registration and authentication.

In FIDO2, the equivalent seems to be the *relying party identifier*, which is defined to be a domain name, like `example.com`.

The *relying party identifier* and the *application identity* serve the same purpose in both FIDO2/CTAP2 and U2F. However, CTAP2 authenticators get the *relying party identifier* directly as an UTF8 string, whereas U2F authenticators only get a SHA-256 hash of the *application identity* (the *application parameter*).

The [FIDO documentation for CTAP](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.0-ps-20190130/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.0-ps-20190130.html) describes [how CTAP2 maps onto CTAP1/U2F](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.0-ps-20190130/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.0-ps-20190130.html#u2f-interoperability). In it, they simply treat the *relying party identifier* directly as the *application identity*:

> Let rpIdHash be a byte array of size 32 initialized with SHA-256 hash of rp.id parameter as CTAP1/U2F application parameter (32 bytes)

[image: Graphic from CTAP documentation]

This seems inconsistent. Let's say I were `example.com`, and I adopted U2F second-factor authentication early on. My *application id* would be `https://example.com`, so my original U2F application parameter would be `SHA256("https://example.com")`:

```
100680ad546ce6a577f42f52df33b4cfdca756859e664b8d7de329b150d09ce9
```

But if I then switched over to using Webauthn, my *relying party identifier* would just be `example.com`. When that is converted to a *U2F application parameter* as described in [section 7 of fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.0](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.0-ps-20190130/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.0-ps-20190130.html#u2f-interoperability), the resulting value should be `SHA256("example.com")`:

```
a379a6f6eeafb9a55e378c118034e2751e682fab9f2d30ab13d2125586ce1947
```

That is obviously different. Anyone who had previously set up their U2F keys for use with my website would no longer be able to use them after I switched to WebAuthn: unless they re-registered with their keys. And, of course, they would need to be able to log-in to do that.

Digging deeper, I noticed that the example they gave in the documentation had a *relying party identifier* of `example.com`, but the hash they gave in the example was...

```
1194228DA8FDBDEEFD261BD7B6595CFD70A50D70C6407BCF013DE96D4EFB17DE
```

Which isn't *either* of the above two options. It remains unclear to me what string hashes to that value.

So what am I getting wrong here? How could services that deployed 2FA using U2F ever switch to FIDO2/Webauthn without requiring their users to re-register their security keys? I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebAuthn supports backward compatibility with U2F via the [AppID Extension documented in the W3C WebAuthn spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#sctn-appid-extension). The Relying Party (RP) passes the U2F *application identity* to the browser via this extension.

Here are a few RP AppID examples in [Python](https://github.com/Yubico/python-fido2/blob/cff406e4bfc03d1aad3379cb70cb3f248f9e6fb0/fido2/server.py#L309) and [Java](https://github.com/Yubico/java-webauthn-server/blob/557822ae9143979ed51868af0883c3cd51b843e3/webauthn-server-demo/src/main/java/demo/webauthn/WebAuthnServer.java#L136).

Comment: Here's a [guide with Ruby code examples](https://github.com/cedarcode/webauthn-ruby/blob/master/docs/u2f_migration.md).